# Set default start page for Angular routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I would want main.htm to be the default page that comes up without having to type mysite.com/main.htm. I would prefer it comes up right with mysite.com. When I click on the Main link with the site below it does go to mysite.com (localhost right now as I'm using Visual Studio to run this) but that doesn't get routed to main.htm. How can I get main.htm to be the "default" page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <p><a href="/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="red">Red</a>
    <a href="green">Green</a>
    <a href="blue">Blue</a>

    <!-- below is where the partial pages will replace -->
    <div ng-view></div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "main.htm"
        })
        .when("/red", {
            templateUrl : "red.htm"
        })
        .when("/green", {
            templateUrl : "green.htm"
        })
        .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl : "blue.htm"
        });

        // note: when you do this you must have the <base> tag in the header as well
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1x8gswxIwmdoXiEgSLDK?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the name has to be index.htm not main.htm and then it works.

[EDIT]

Of course when I do that the other routes (red/green/blue) aren't working now.

[Edit] added a plunker to my original post in comments

Comment: Can you add a plunker link please?

Comment: nevermind, I deleted the r in routeProvider so that's why it wasn't routing, but now it's crashing right away. It shows the page for a second then crashes chrome and it goes to it's "Aw Snap" crash page. I'll test on a site like that.

Comment: OK, so it looks like if I have the mapping for "/" with the templateUrl as index.htm it causes the crash (infinite loop maybe?). Guessing index.htm starts up by default sees the route which it then tries to change to that which starts it up again, and so on? So guessing if I have a name index.htm in the base directory I shouldn't route to it as IIS Express is starting it by default anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as your `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="#red">Red</a>
    <a href="#green">Green</a>
    <a href="#blue">Blue</a>

    <!-- below is where the partial pages will replace -->
    <div ng-view></div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "main.htm"
        })
        .when("/red", {
            templateUrl : "red.htm"
        })
        .when("/green", {
            templateUrl : "green.htm"
        })
        .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl : "blue.htm"
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the pretty urls.

Comment: So this works, but when I try to get pretty urls I can't get it to work. Can you try an example with pretty urls because that's what is breaking it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use state instead route ?
When I do this with my app :

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['starter.controllers','starter.services','ui.router'])

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider


  .state('green', {
    url: "/green",
    templateUrl: 'templates/green.htm'
  })

  .state('red', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/red',
    templateUrl: 'templates/red.htm'
  })

  .state('blue', {
    url: '/blue',
    templateUrl: 'templates/blue.htm'
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/red'); //red become the default view

});
```

And in template :

```
<a ui-sref="red">Red</a>
<a ui-sref="green">Green</a>
<a ui-sref="blue">Blue</a>
```

For me it's work, can you try ?

Comment: I've never used states before. Is this available in 1.5.8? I'd have to read up on states to see if I wanted to use that method of routing vs the one I'm using I guess. It's hard to keep up with all this stuff and the different ways to do it.